# Computed or Stored Property?

Tags: ios, swift, properties

So, I'm porting my Android app to iOS and I'm getting my feet wet with Swift (3).

I understand the concept of Computed properties and I'm trying to use them as much as I can, however it got me thinking that maybe I'm overdoing it and this will have a performance impact on my app.

So my scenario:
I have a class with two Strings, one of them is my username that is global thought my app and the other is the opponent's username. So my code is something like this:

```
class Game {
    let player: String
    let opponent: String
    var iAmPlayer: Bool {
        return player.caseInsensitiveCompare(GlobalUsername) == .orderedSame
    }

    init(player: String, opponent: String) {
        self.player = player
        self.opponent = opponent
    }
}
```

I check my iAmPlayer boolean quite often, to see if the user started the game or not, especially when ordering the game objects. In java, I just have a boolean variable that I set when I initialise my object. I was wondering, is it better if I just use a Stored property here instead of what I'm doing? Are computed properties optimised, or the calculation is taking place every single time I try to access the iAmPlayer var?

P.S.: Once the Game object is created, player and opponent don't change. (thus the let)

Comment: Yes, the calculation takes place every time your reference `iAmPlayer`. A stored property would therefore be a tad more efficient. (I assume that not only can neither `player` nor `opponent` change, but also `GlobalUsername` too?)

Comment: This could only ever be optimized away in circumstances in which `player` and `GlobalUsername` haven't changed, and only if the compiler can deduce that `caseInsensitiveCompare` is referentially transparent. It's certainly possible, but you'll have to see the generated code to see for yourself.

Comment: @Rob yes, none of the values can change. If anything changes, a new Game object will be created, as these are fetched from my server.
I also have some other classes where I do the same with vars, that *can* change. Is a computed property better suited there?

Comment: @Alexander so your suggestion is that I should use a stored property for my boolean since it can't be optimised, or do you actually mean to look at the generated code? (and if so, how?)

Comment: @LucasP. Until you've profiled your app and identified it as a performance issue, I would stick to whatever technique you find cleanest and easiest. I would personally prefer a stored property, but that's just me

Comment: if `player` can not change and also `GobalUserName` (btw: is it a var or costant? it looks like class) then you only need to set it once while you create the class `Game`

Comment: @muescha Well, it's a string that the app gets form my server once the user logs in. (Not yet implemented in iOS but it there will be a global object called UserManager that provides all the needed strings, so GlobalUsername will be something like Usermanager.instance.username, once I figure out the correct way to have shared global objects in iOS)

Thanks for the answer guys! I'll leave it as it is for now, and maybe I'll change it to a stored property down the road, as I have it in my java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thx to other comments on below the question
i uset `Usermanager.instance.username` instead of `GlobalUsername`

#### 1.Solution: move calculation to Init

- pro: no changes to any other code
- con: still has a reference to the UserManager

Code:

```
class Game {
    let playerName: String
    let opponentName: String
    var isCurrentUser: Bool

    init(playerName: String, opponentName: String) {
        self.playerName = playerName
        self.opponentName = opponentName
        self.isCurrentUser = playerName.caseInsensitiveCompare(UserManager.instance.currentUserName) == .orderedSame
    }
}

// Create Game object

Game(playerName: gameData.playerName, 
    opponentName: gameData.opponentName)
```

#### 2. Solution: give the current userName to the init

- pro: no implicit out connections - decoupling of object
- pro: testable without to set the Usermanager
- con: you have to change the creation of Game init

Code:

```
class Game {
    let playerName: String
    let opponentName: String
    var isCurrentUser: Bool

    init(playerName: String, opponentName: String, currentUserName: String) {
        self.playerName = playerName
        self.opponentName = opponentName
        self.isCurrentUser = playerName.caseInsensitiveCompare(currentUserName) == .orderedSame
    }
}

// Create Game object

Game(playerName: gameData.playerName, 
    opponentName: gameData.opponentName, 
    currentUserName: UserManager.instance.currentUserName)
```

#### 3. Solution: move calculation of the bool outside of creation

- pro: no implicit out connections - decoupling of object
- pro: testable without to set the Usermanager
- pro: change logic of calculation for "isCurrentUser" without changing the Game object
- con: you have to change the creation of Game init

Code:

```
class Game {
    let playerName: String
    let opponentName: String
    var isCurrentUser: Bool

    init(playerName: String, opponentName: String, isCurrentUser: Bool) {
        self.playerName = playerName
        self.opponentName = opponentName
        self.isCurrentUser = isCurrentUser
    }
}

// Create Game object

var currentUserName = UserManager.instance.currentUserName
var isCurrentUser = dameData.playerName.caseInsensitiveCompare(currentUserName) == .orderedSame

Game(playerName: gameData.playerName, 
    opponentName: gameData.opponentName, 
    isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser)


// Create Game object

var isCurrentUser = UserManager.instance.isCurrentUser(gameData.playerName)

Game(playerName: gameData.playerName, 
    opponentName: gameData.opponentName, 
    isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser)
```